# In kinematics are all of the equations linear functions?

Tags: kinematics

For example In ($ \frac{Δx} {\Delta t} $)=( $\frac{v0+vf} {2} $),is ($ \frac{Δx} {\Delta t} $) a linear function of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all kinematic equations are linear. For example,

$$x=\frac12at^2,$$

giving the displacement under constant acceleration when starting from rest, is quadratic in the time.

Your equation for the average velocity is independent of the time.